# How to select the 2nd children element (div) and not just its content?

Tags: jquery, html

is there a way to get the html using jquery (or javascript):

```
<div class="elem2 elem"><span>text2.1</span><span>text2.2</span></div>
```

from this html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem1 elem">
    <span>text1.1</span>
    <span>text1.2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="elem2 elem">
    <span>text2.1</span>
    <span>text2.2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

?

I tried using several ways:

```
alert($('div.container').children().eq(1).html());
alert($('div.container > :nth-child(2)')).html());
alert($($('div.container').children()[1]).html());
alert($('div.elem2').html());
```

but it always return me the same result:

```
<span>text2.1</span> <span>text2.2</span>
```

without the warper div.

I've put an example of the code in:
http://jsfiddle.net/kZBUr/

plz help!!

Comment: you will get in few seconds..wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the native `outerHTML` property, though it isn't supported in all browsers. Here's a cross-browser solution.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/kZBUr/3/

```
var selected = $('div.container > .elem2.elem');

selected = selected[0].outerHTML || $('<div>').append(selected.clone()).html();

$('#result').text(selected);
```

Comment: var selected = $('div.container > :nth-child(2)'); - to dynamically select the nth child.

Comment: i just didnt get what does the selected[0].outerHTML is for.

Comment: @Seeker - It first attempts to use the native `outerHTML` property because that is much faster. When you place `[0]` after the jQuery object, you're pulling the first DOM element out of it. This way you can access its native `outerHTML`. If the browser doesn't support that property, it will return `undefined`, and the code will attempt the jQuery solution.

Comment: aha! that's why that part of the code wasn't working (using firefox 3.6.12). but the rest ot it works just fine. ty again :D

Comment: @Seeker - Yes, if you were trying to use `outerHTML` alone (without the second half) in Firefox, it would fail since [it is unfortunately not supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t05).

Answer (score 1):

you already selected 2nd child. wrapper text ( and ) is not part of elements html.
for example:
$('div.container > :nth-child(2)').attr('class') will return elem2 elem

Comment: Ty for the info. I didn't realize it.

Comment: try with $('div.container > :nth-child(2)').appendTo(some selector);

Comment: hmmm. i've tried and it actualy puts the <div class="elem2 elem"> in the code. not exactly what i wanted but it's good to know other ways to manipulate my code. ty

Comment: here it is:
$('div.container > :nth-child(2)').clone().appendTo('#target');

Answer (score 0):

I think the .eq(1) function is zero-based index.

Try this instead:

```
alert($('div.container').children().eq(0).html());
alert($('div.container > :nth-child(1)')).html());
alert($($('div.container').children()[0]).html());
alert($('div.elem2').html());
```

Comment: I was trying to get the 2nd div (elem2). What u are sugesting is for the 1st div (elem1).